# Storing data from Angular subscribe in property

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I have a method in a service called getWeather. It contacts an API with given longitude and latitude and returns the response:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OpenWeatherService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getWeather(lat, long) {
    return this.http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + long + "&appid=hiddenappid");
  }
}
```

I am using it in a component that makes some calculations based on the information it returns. I'm attempting to store the information it sends back in a property called "weatherData" but since the http.get method is asynchronous it lets the undefined weatherData property be printed to the console first. How can I work around this? Here is the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { OpenWeatherService } from '../open-weather.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-weather',
  templateUrl: './weather.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./weather.component.css']
})
export class WeatherComponent implements OnInit {

  public weatherSearchForm: FormGroup;
  public weatherData: any;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private OpenWeatherService: OpenWeatherService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.weatherSearchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      longitude: [''],
      latitude: ['']
    })
  }

  sendToOpenWeather(formValues) {
    this.OpenWeatherService
    .getWeather(formValues.longitude, formValues.latitude)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.weatherData = data; 
      // prints the correct longitude and latitude
      console.log(this.weatherData);
     });
    // prints undefined
    console.log(this.weatherData);    
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't reach data from outside of async function. You need to do your process in subscribe. What do you want to do with data ?

Comment: @pc_coder I wanted to get the weather, then base the user interface on it. Make a calculation based on the weather that comes back from the api. Sort of like, if (the weather is a certain temperature) { the user interface will look like this }. But beyond this silly program, assuming I wanted to take the data from the API and stick it in a property, then use that property for something else, how can I go about this?

Comment: write one function that take parameter as as result of api respons than do your function insede there then call your function inside subscribe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reach data from outside of async function. You need to do your process in subscribe.

```
doProcess(){
   //do your process in this function
   console.log(this.weatherData);
}
```

in subscribe call this. function

```
sendToOpenWeather(formValues) {    
     this.OpenWeatherService
      .getWeather(formValues.longitude, formValues.latitude)
       .subscribe(data => {
          this.weatherData = data; 
          this.doProcess();
     });
}
```